# javascript check if value is date or nonnumerical string to stop reformatting function

Tags: javascript, r, plotly

Fairly new javascript user here:

How do I change this javascript if statement that should return `FALSE` for `dates` and `strings` wrapped around a value transformation code block. In the app below it should cause values to be transformed to scientific notation, while not altering dates and name variables.

```
  return (Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object Number]' || Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object String]') &&!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n.toString().replace(/^-/, ''));
```

additional info: Plotly uses an Unicode minus sign instead of a regular dash I heared, so I already tried using `.replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-'))` somewhere in the code, but no success.

**Supplementary Explanation:** 
I'm building some javascript into my R shiny plotly work to manipulate ticks on the plot axes, but I have run into some problems how to make the code deal with certain values.

Goal: 
transform POS and NEG values to scientific annotation
DON'T transform Dates 
DON'T transform text values (or factors)
So strictly transform numbers

using this line works to transform pos and neg values on the y axis in the demo app below:

```
if(parseInt(d.text) !== 0)
```

but also makes a mess of dates ( plotting `x = ~Date` in the app below), or names (plotting `x = rownames(x)` in the app below.

I tried using a javascript code that I found on SO somewhere to check for numeric, but it is not having the desired effect.

i.e. changing the previous line to this:

```
if(parseInt(d.text) !== 0 && isNumber(parseInt(d.text)))
```

**MY APP**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(

  plotlyOutput('plotly'),
  br(),
  actionButton(inputId = 'Saveplot', label = icon('floppy-o'), style = "height:40px; width:40px; border-radius: 6px; border-width:3px; border-color:#339fff; 
              color: #339fff; background-color:#fff; font-size:1.4em")
)

server <- function(input, output){
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg *-1
mtcarsBig <-rbindlist(list(mtcars, mtcars2))
mtcarsBig$Date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 96)
```

mtcarsBig$gear <- as.factor(mtcarsBig$gear)
mtcarsBig$brand <- rep(c('Honda', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Volvo'), 8)

```
  javascript <- "
  function(el, x) 
  {
    function isNumber(n) {
      return (Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object Number]' || Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object String]') &&!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n.toString().replace(/^-/, ''));
    }
    function fixTicks()
    {
      ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.yaxislayer-above,g.xaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
      ticks.each(function(d) 
      {
        if(parseInt(d.text) !== 0 && isNumber(parseInt(d.text)))
        {
var num = parseInt(d.text.replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-')).toExponential(2);
          Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num);
        }
      })
    }
    el.on('plotly_afterplot', fixTicks);
  }"


  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    p <- mtcarsBig %>% 
      split(mtcarsBig$cyl) %>% 
      purrr::map(., function(x) {
        plot_ly(data = x, 
                x = ~Date, 
                y = ~mpg, 
                type = "bar") %>%
          layout( )
      }) %>% 
      subplot(nrows = 3, margin = 0.03)


    p$elementId <- NULL   ## to surpress warning of widgetid
    p <- onRender(p, javascript)
    p
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you add a few examples for each category, i.e. numeric vs. non-numeric?

Comment: mtcarsBig$Date is dates, mtcarsBig$brand is string column and mtcars$cyl is factor now Max. you can plot those as x axis instead of one of the numerical ones. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery` has a nice function `isNumeric` to check if a variable is numeric, possibly after coercion if it is a string.

Try

```
if($.isNumeric(d.text) && parseInt(d.text) !== 0)
```